# Inserting TimeStamp Column from List to MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a List like shown below (The list has been obtained by converting a pandas dataframe to a list. The pandas dataframe is obtained from an excel):

- **L = [[3982, 36308220021, Timestamp('2017-07-01 14:10:37'), '', Timestamp('2017-07-01 14:20:48'), '', 0, 0]]**

Note: L is actually a nested list with more than 5000 entries.

I am inserting the values in MySQL using python . There I have defined the column as "**dateACW DATETIME**" during **CREATE TABLE** operations. Similar column names have been defined for other Timestamp values from the list. During insertion in MySQL, it gives following error: ***"AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'"***. I tried using TIMESTAMP datatype instead of DATETIME. That did not help. Please help me out with explanation on whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use to_pydatetime() function to convert it to datetime.

```
timestamp = pd.Timestamp('2017-07-01 14:10:37', tz=None)

timestamp.to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: Actually, the list is very huge. It's a list of list with more than 5000 entries. Is there a quick way which can convert all the entries with prefixed "Timestamp ( *****)" into an appropriate entry for MySQL INSERT query.